# Variables optimized out or unavailable running GDB in a VM

Tags: c++, gdb, virtual-machine, vmware-fusion

I'm running Windows 10 in a VMware Fusion virtual machine on MacOS and compiling (`-O0 -g`) with MinGW. I can set breakpoints, but when execution stops, almost all of the variables are listed as optimized out and pointers are at `0x0`. There are ongoing operations on these items. Any ideas on what's happening?

Edit: When I pass one of these variables to a function, it does become visible in that function.

Comment: It can be that your gdb is misconfigured somehow or it can be that you indeed try to debug something that has been optimized out compile time. How should we know?

Comment: I have no idea if my gdb is misconfigured. Every variable is coming up as optimized out or unavailable. Even odder, this hasn't always been the case, and I've no idea what changed. I'm hoping that someone has seen this problem when working in a VM and can chime in. I've no problems tracing this same block of code when running it in on Ubuntu in a Linux KVM.